# In PHP fopen() in 'a' mode changes line endings

Tags: php, fopen

I'm opening a text file for append with

```
$fp = fopen('textfile.dat','a');
```

then writing tab, separated values with:

```
 fputs($fp, PHP_EOL . implode(array_values($features), "\t"));
```

Can't use fputcsv because of problems with field enclosures.

Here's the problem:
After writing, the line endings on all lines before the append file pointer get changed to ^M, but the new lines written with the above code are the correct "\n" character.

This is on an Ubuntu 12.04 server running php 5.3

Answer (score 0):

> After writing, the line endings on all lines before the append file pointer get changed to ^M, but the new lines written with the above code are the correct "\n" character.

Except this is impossible.

The other possible explanation is that you're not generating the same line ending that already exists in the file; you will need to read the file, figure out what line endings are being used, and output them yourself as well.

Comment: The original line endings show as normal in emacs, but after opening for append then saving, those same line endings change to ^M in emacs, and my newly added lines are "\n". 

HOWEVER, when I tried making my new lines end with "\n\r", I don't see the ^M in emacs.
The file never touches a Microsoft product.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Nope. But it's not impossible that something somewhere along the line uses CRLF instead of LF.